# Issues with Schema Design

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I am designing a database having the following entities :
`Student_detail` : has `id` as PK and rest some attributes.
`Event` : Has the details about different events. `event_no` is PK. (there are about 32 events)
`Participates_in` : is a relation between `student_detail` and `event`, has both their PKs as FKs.
`Team_with` : this is a relation from `student_detail` table to itself, it has 8 `participant` columns, one `team_id` column, one `for_event_no` column(FK to event_no). All the `participant` columns are FKs to `student_detail.id`.

One row of this column indicates a team for a specific event.
The number 8 because, the max team size in all events is 8.
Events have variable number of allowed team sizes.
I devised the team_with table in order to avoid creating 30 different tables for different event.
Due to this, query length is increasing. Is this good design? I would like suggestions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all members of a team have equal membership?  If there were 8 fixed roles in a team, I would agree with your design.  If not, I suggest:

```
teams (team_id PK, for_event_no FK)
team_members (team_id PK/FK, student_detail_id PK/FK)
```

However, enforcing a maximum team size of 8 could be more difficult.  I don't see this as a significant problem since you say different events allow different team sizes, so the limit of 8 could be incorporated into that mechanism, however it's implemented.

What's the difference between participation in an event and membership of a team associated with the event?  There's already a relation between `Event` and `Student_detail` - directly in your `Team_with`, and transitively in my suggestion.  `Participates_in` may be redundant, unless participation is possible without being part of a team.

Comment: every event has different team size. The max of these team sizes is 8 (there is an event with team size as 8, rest all have less than that). Even i was starting to think that one out of `Participates_in` and `team_with` is redundant.

Comment: How about this, in `participates_in`, i would include columns `team_id (int)` and and `is_leader (bool)` and drop `team_with`

Comment: Can a student belong to more than one team per event?

Comment: No, but he can be in multiple events

Comment: Your idea sounds ok.  If you have `teams (team_id PK, event_no FK)` then you can drop `event_no` from `participates_in` unless you want to use it to enforce a unique constraint on `(student_detail_id, event_no)`.